# File security using htaccess blocking regular pdf file

Tags: security, .htaccess, file-upload

I read [this](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/upload-forms-threat.htm) artcile on file upload security, but now it seems that a valid pdf I uploaded is being given access forbidden after implenting this htaccess on top of the other security methods mentioned:

```
deny from all
<Files ~ "^\w+\.(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|doc|docx|txt|rtf|ppt|pptx|xls|mp4|mov|mp3|mpg|mpeg)$">
order deny,allow
allow from all
</Files>
```

The file name looks like this:
Company-apv-A4-Solarpanels_ABC-RH.pdf

Which should be fine because the htaccess is meant to prevent the doubled extension attack if I understand correctly. Hope someone can help!

Comment: _doubled extension attack_ (which is only a problem for Microsoft Windows users with the _Hide known file types_ option _ON_ which is an option, I always turn _OFF_) would mean a file named `OpenMe.pdf.exe` (which would appear to the user as `OpenMe.pdf`) or the like which that regex doesn't match. -- Why protect Windows users from a problem created by Microsoft?

Comment: I think the article explains it pretty well; that the mime type can be tricked, and this applies to apache as well, meaning a php script could potentially be embedded into an image for instance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(^|/)[-\w]+\.(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|doc|docx|txt|rtf|ppt|pptx|xls|mp4|mov|mp3|mpg|mpeg)$" allowed

<Files *>
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from env=allowed
</Files>
```

Also note that I dropped the mandatory leading ^ as you surely want to allow access to these extensions in subdirs and `[-\w]+` as `-` is not in `\w`.

I would just start my regexp `\.(gif`... as you really only need to check the extension for what you want.  Up to you.

Comment: Hi Terry, thanks for the reply. Looks good, but before I implement, I would like to understand a bit better, a bit complicated for me... if I understand right from here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_setenvif.html the setenvif checks the http headers of the file for validity. I think that is what my original script does too. Also the original script seems to work fine in subdirectories too

Comment: There are two aspects (i) You will never match `ABC-RH.pdf` against `\w+\.pdf`.  The `\w` meta does not include "``".  You need `[-\w]*` here, or to drop it (what if a file includes `%20`?).  (ii) **SetEnvIf** vs **FilesMatch** vs **Files ~**: this is a really matter of preference than performance.  I like my pattern because the intent is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this while researching a solution for something else. But, to make an easier solution, since you basically wanted to prevent all double extensions, you should use this:

```
Order Allow,Deny
<FilesMatch "^[^.]+\.(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|doc|docx|txt|rtf|ppt|pptx|xls|mp4|mov|mp3|mpg|mpeg)$">
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

More to the point and simpler. Using `FilesMatch` (as `FilesMatch` utilizes REGEX better and more than `Files` does) it uses the '`Order Allow, Deny`' directive which means, match allow or deny, if not matching either, then deny. So this denies all except what's allowed.

`[^.]` means any character 'not' a literal period. So that covers pretty much everything that you were wanting to achieve. Just remember that these rules do no allow for upper case file extensions. Some people use older apps that create upper case file extensions, so you may want to include those as well.

I'm not sure how well the '`/i`' case insensitivity works with `Files` or `FilesMatch` so you may want to do character classes like this:

```
([Jj][Pp][Ee]?[Gg]|[Pp][Nn][Gg]|[Gg][Ii][Ff]|[Pp][Dd][Ff])
```

and so on.